# g++ link against static library does not work

Tags: c++, windows, g++, static-linking, lib

I have a simle file main.cpp and static library MyLib.lib and I am trying to link program against static library like this:

```
g++ -o m main.cpp -static -L c:\lib\path -l MyLib
```

or like this:

```
g++ -o m main.cpp -L c:\lib\path -Wl,-Bstatic -l MyLib -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

The compilation process exits successfully and without error. However when I try to run m.exe from command line I get error that it cannot be run because MyLib.dll cannot be found.

I specificaly said it should compile against static lib MyLib.lib so why is it searching for a dynamic library? Did I made an error in commands above?

Comment: Is there a reason to use gcc on Windows?

Comment: *I do not have a dll file. I have only a lib file.* This is important information from your comment and should be added to the question. Since you link MyLib.lib and then get "MyLib.dll cannot be found", you link with improper MyLib.lib, that is a lib for linking with MyLib.dll

Answer (score -1):

It really looks like you linked with a shared library.
You need to add the location of the folder containing MyLib.dll to the PATH.
In a Command Prompt type this:

```
SET PATH=<dll_location>;%PATH%
m.exe
```

or make sure MyLib.dll is in the same folder as m.exe.

If gcc only finds a shared library there is a chance the static flags didn't work.

Why is your library not called libMyLib.a? The name MyLib.lib seems to imply you got it prebuilt from MSVC. If so, how do you know MyLib.lib is not a shared library?

Is there a way you can build MyLib yourself as a static library?

Comment: I do not have a dll file. I have only a lib file. The library is only in static version.

Comment: You seem to have linked against a shared library since it's looking for MyLib.dll.
How sure are you the library you linked against was static?